# create associative array from multi dimensional associative post array - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have created a form that produces a multi-dimensional post array. I want to change to array so I can insert it into my table.

This is the post array that is returned.

```
Array
(
  [project_no] => 160
  [result] => Array
    (
        [5] => Array
            (
                [temp_dwg_rev] => D
                [temp_dwg_id] => 5
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [temp_dwg_rev] => D
                [temp_dwg_id] => 6
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [temp_dwg_rev] => E
                [temp_dwg_id] => 7
            )
    )


    [client] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [client_id] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [client_id] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

So I suppose that array should look something like this to get the query to work

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 5
        [temp_dwg_rev] => D
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 6
        [temp_dwg_rev] => D
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 7
        [temp_dwg_rev] => E
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 1
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 5
        [temp_dwg_rev] => D
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 6
        [temp_dwg_rev] => D
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [temp_dwg_id] => 7
        [temp_dwg_rev] => E
        [project_no] => 160
        [client_id] => 3
    )
)
```

My table in the db looks like this. Note `slip_id` is auto incremented.

```
|slip_id |project_no |client_id |temp_dwg_id |temp_dwg_rev
|1       |160        |1         |5           |D
|2       |160        |1         |6           |D
|3       |160        |1         |7           |E
|4       |160        |3         |5           |D
|5       |160        |3         |6           |D
|6       |160        |3         |7           |E
```

I've tried the following code but this create an array with just temp_dwg_id, temp_dwg_rev and project_on in an associative array. I still need to add the client array to this

```
        $drawings = $_POST['result'];
        $dist = $_POST['client'];
        $project_no = $_POST['project_no'];

        $test = array();
        foreach ($drawings as $row)
        {
            $test[$row['temp_dwg_id']]['temp_dwg_id']= $row['temp_dwg_id'];
            $test[$row['temp_dwg_id']]['temp_dwg_rev']= $row['temp_dwg_rev'];
            $test[$row['temp_dwg_id']]['project_no']= $project_no;

        }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
foreach($dist as $client)
{
  foreach($drawings as $drawing)
  {
    //determine the index for your current drawings
    $index = count($test);
    $test[$index]['temp_dwg_id']= $drawing['temp_dwg_id'];
    $test[$index]['temp_dwg_rev']= $drawing['temp_dwg_rev'];
    $test[$index]['project_no']= $project_no;
    $test[$index]['client_id']= $client['client_id'];
  }
}
```

Edited to show example using array_push()

```
foreach($dist as $client)
{
  foreach($drawings as $drawing)
  {
    $newDrawing = array(
      'temp_dwg_id'  => $drawing['temp_dwg_id'],
      'temp_dwg_rev' => $drawing['temp_dwg_rev'],
      'project_no'   => $project_no,
      'client_id'    => $client['client_id'],
    );
    array_push($test, $newDrawing);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much that worked very well. I'm still trying to figure out why it works. However I get an error message for `client_id` that says this **Message: Illegal string offset 'client_id'**

Comment: I figured out why it was giving an error. I change something on the form in the view page.

Comment: why not use `array_push()` instead?

Comment: @Juan-EmilSaayman, the reason it works is you start looping through each of your clients first and FOREACH client, you then loop through the drawings as from your example, each client receives every drawing. So you need to start with the client and add each drawing.

Comment: @CodeGodie, yes you could just as easy use `array_push()` however, I wanted to show where the index was coming from so he could try to see how the new array was being created like the example he posted.